# Как создать поле в структуре данных, которое равно этой структуре данных Python?

Tags: python, ооп

Есть условный класс vector2:

```
class v2:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x; self.y = y
```

Хотелось бы добавить поля, как в Unity/C# в Vector2, по типу Vector2.Up

```
class v2:
    Up = v2(0, -1)
```

Как это можно правильно реализовать, если можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, можно сделать вот так, т. е. просто добавить это поле после создания класса:

```py
class v2:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


v2.up = v2(0, -1)
```

Но, по-моему, более питонично будет создать просто отдельные константы:

```py
UP = v2(0, -1)
```